# Multiple IF in Laravel HasRole

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have an if that validates the access to the user according to the Role
Currently I have it like this but I want to change the access to 2 roles.

My original variable is this:

`if ($user->hasRole('Delivery Guy')) {`
.... rest of the code.

I need that if to be something like this, try this but it doesn't work.

`if ($user->hasRole('Delivery Guy' || 'Store Owner')) {`

I need that if to allow access with both roles.

Thanks!

Comment: Dear @john-lobo I found the solution by trying and testing Thank you very much for your time :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of the following solutions.

```
$user->hasRole(['Delivery Guy', 'Store Owner']);

$user->hasAnyRole(['Delivery Guy', 'Store Owner']);

$user->hasAnyRole('Delivery Guy', 'Store Owner');
```

[Read More about Roles/Permissions](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/role-permissions)

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution thanks

`if ($user->hasRole(['Delivery Guy', 'Store Owner'])) {`

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

if ($user->hasRole(['Delivery Guy', 'Store Owner'])) {

}

OR

if ($user->hasRole('Delivery Guy') || $user->hasRole('Store Owner')) {

}

Comment: Please Write Down More Deescription.